# Scaled <a> within a list appears bigger than the ancestor elements

Tags: css, height, transform, adjustment

```
Text
```

Hi there,

first I have to say: I´m a beginner, so I hope you are patient with me!:-)

I created a navigation via a list. By adding a "padding" for "a" I determined also the height of its ancestor elements ("ul" and "nav"). I did that because afterwards I wanted the whole areas to get black with a transition.

Now, when I want to scale it to 1.2, the "a"-clicking-area appears bigger than the ancestor arease of "ul" and "nav".

Any ideas how I can limit it to the height of the link area?

```
image
```

[Link to picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0hRP.png)

```
CSS and html code
```

````
<!-- language: lang-css -->

* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

strong, b {
    font-weight: bold;
}

em, i {
    font-style: *italic*;
}

small {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

main h1,
main p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

main h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: **bold**;
}

main p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

main :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    height: 30rem;
    background-image: url(../images/whatsapp.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right bottom;
    position: relative;
}

header a {
    color: white;
}

/*Breakpoint 1*/
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    header {
        height: 20rem;
    }
}

header #title {
    font-size: 7.5rem;
    font-weight: **bold**;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;

    word-spacing: -0.05em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    left: calc(50% - 30rem);
    opacity: 0.75;
}

/*Breakpoint 1*/
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
header #title {
    font-size: 5rem; 
    font-weight: **bold**;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;

    word-spacing: -0.05em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    left: calc(60% - 30rem);
    opacity: 0.75;            
    }
}

header #title::before {
    content: url(../images/sun.svg);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 30%;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-right: 2rem; 
    margin-left: 1rem; 
}

/*Breakpoint 2*/ 
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    header #title, header #title::before {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        top: calc(30rem - 100%); 
        left: -6rem; 
    }

    header #title {
        font-size: 2.8rem;
    }
    header #title::before {
        width: 20%;
        margin-right: 0rem;
        margin-left: 2.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
}

nav {
    width: 100%; 

    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);

    position: absolute; 
    top: 321px;
}

nav ul {
    max-width: 1025px;
    
    display: flex;   
    justify-content: space-around; 
    margin: auto; 
}

nav ul li {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: **bold**;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul li a {
    padding: 4rem 2rem; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;

    padding: 4rem 2rem;
}


@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        width: 180px;
        height: inherit;
        position: unset;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    
    }

    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;

    }

    nav ul li a {
        padding: 1.03rem; 
        text-align: left;  
    }
}

main {
    max-width: 1025px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

```  
html code
```

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>  
            <title>Whatsapp</title>
            <link href="styles/styles_neu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        </head>
        <body>
        
            <header>
                <a href="#" id="title">Whatsapp</a>
                
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">1</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">3</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">4</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            
            <main>
            
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            
            </main>
        
        </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
````

Comment: Can you show us the rules that contain styles_neu.css plz ?

Comment: Hey @The_Death_Raw , thanks for helping me! I´m not sure exactly what you mean with rules, that contain the Css? I added the html and css code in my request. Or do you mean the cutout of my problem? :-)

Comment: I found it out by myself now! :-)
Transition on a:hover